# Why don’t you want to moderate for Sound Design?

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

A few weeks ago, we [announced](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1453/insufficient-nominees-for-moderator-election-what-happens-next) to the Sound Design community that we had trouble getting the necessary number of nominations to hold a graduation election. We hoped that this would start a conversation on the need for nominations for moderators on the site.

We have greatly appreciated Rory Alsop and AJ Henderson’s work to keep the site well moderated. We need the election to be competitive to hold one. Since this is a graduation election, that means we need at least four nominations for it to be successful. If we have another unsuccessful election, Sound Design will be at risk of being closed.

**So why don’t you want to moderate for Sound Design?**

Answer (score 1):

Personally, it's because I don't actually like being in charge unless I have absolute certainty in any given topic.

In the studio or on stage I can be in charge because I know my environment & other people working there. In here there are too many topics that fall too far outside my own personal experience, so hesitancy would mean I would avoid making binding decisions.

Comment: The nice thing about being a moderator is you are not truly in charge like a boss over a team. Instead, you are helping to keep the lights on and make sure things stay orderly. The best part is that you are part of a team that works together, so you never have to make a judgment call yourself.

Comment: In addition, moderators on Stack Exchange sites aren't expected to be subject matter experts on everything to do with the site. As noted on the help center page ["Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?"](https://sound.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators): "Moderators are human exception handlers, there to deal with those exceptional conditions that could otherwise disrupt the community." Mods mostly deal with flags (e.g. cleaning up comments or spam/abuse, intervening to stop arguments, etc.). You don't need to know everything about the topic of the site to be a mod. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it's because I don't have enough rep to nominate myself!

Comment: With the next election likely to be in early 2022, you have plenty of time to gain enough rep :-)

Comment: Just to echo Rory here. But there is plenty of time to accumulate the rep needed. With the election not being held til early next year, there is more than enough time to get it.

Comment: @SpencerG the site stats don't make that seem possible. In the [past quarter **one** person earned **170** reputation](https://sound.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=quarter), add 101 to that and it's insufficient to become a candidate for nomination. The next lowest is only 109 and 85 reputation earned in that period of time. --- If you want people to join and volunteer you'll have to hold off on the election for half a year.

Comment: Rob is correct.

Answer (score -2):

> So why don’t you want to moderate for Sound Design?

- I don't want to moderate a site where [questions get removed for no good reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355097/178179).
- Many mods on SE are taking actions I disagree with: I don't want to be associated with them.
- Sound SE has many overlaps with e.g. Music SE and SU. The [only solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/178179) I know to fix it is not implemented yet, and I don't want to deal with cross-SE duplicates.
- [Serial downvoting is rampant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A178179+%5Bserial-voting%5D) but it seems SE doesn't provide the necessary tools to combat it efficiently.
- I am not keen on volunteering for [for-profit organizations, such as Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190282/178179).
- Some other ideas: [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/178179)