# 2022 Sound Design Community Election - interest check

Tags: discussion, election

It's time for us all to consider holding an election for a new volunteer moderator on Sound Design. We did try to hold an election last year, however there was insufficient interest / folks with the time to step up - we have grown a little as a community, and hopefully there will be potential candidates this time around.

AJ Henderson, and I have been moderators since 2014, when the Sound and Video sites split out into their current structure, and although it's not a lot of work being a moderator on a relatively small SE site, we have grown significantly (our traffic is around 6 times that in 2014 despite a bit of a drop at the start of the Covid pandemic it's picking up again) and we came out of Beta status in 2019 along with a few other sites, so it's worth us checking regularly to see whether anyone would like to join us on the mod team. And although AJ and I typically talk through any disagreements on actions/flags etc, it is generally considered best practice to have a minimum of 3 moderators on a site.

You can also take a look at [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) and the [Theory of moderation (revisited)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) to get a bit of a feeling as to what being a moderator actually entails.

**Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election.**

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up.

Answer (score 2):

I'm willing to run for moderator. I don't mind putting in some time to help.

Comment: Hey n00dles, quick check - are you still interested in running in a Sound Design election?

Comment: @n00dles nominations are open if you are still interested in running as a moderator: [Nominate yourself today! - 2022 Community Moderator Election](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1481/nominate-yourself-today-2022-community-moderator-election)