# Nominate yourself today! - 2022 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

The 2022 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://sound.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Hi folks. We're really looking for folks who can join the existing crew. If you're at all on the fence about running in this election, I'd really encourage just going for it. It's certainly less work than you're expecting - and if you have questions, I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

Done and done! I want to encourage others to do it too! Geet on it! It can't just be ME!! Nominate yourself! What's the worst that could happen?